# The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a project struture like :

```
MyProject
  |
  |-Core/src/main/java/Annotations (a source directory)
       |
       |- abc.xyz.annotations (Package under source directory)
            |
            |-MyClass.java (1 among the classes)
```

Some how sonar doesnot scan my code under such directory structure. But it does work fine if my directory structure is `Core/src/main/java` instead.

With the existing project structure I am getting an error saying

> "The source directory does not correspond to the package declaration abc.xyz.annotations"

I have a `sonar-project.properties` file in my root directory of the project with the below entries in it:

```
sonar.modules=Core
Core.sonar.sources=src/main/java/Annotations
sonar.projectName=MyProject
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adjusting your file structure to your package structure to make things easier to find in the future. That means setting your source folder to `Core/src/main/java/` and in there creating the folder structure `/abc/xyz/annotations`.

This avoids breaking conventions and makes things far easier to read on top of pacifying Sonar

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way we can use such non-conventional custom source directory structures if at all needed? Can sonar be made to scan these directories by using some property configurations?